# How to get last 3 Months of "Monday to Sunday" dates In Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

How can I get last 3 Months of "Monday to Sunday" dates in Redshift?

```
S.no    Start_dt    End_dt  week
1   18-Jul-16   24-Jul-16   Week1
2   25-Jul-16   31-Jul-16   Week2
3   1-Aug-16    7-Aug-16    Week3
4   8-Aug-16    14-Aug-16   Week4
5   15-Aug-16   21-Aug-16   Week5
6   22-Aug-16   28-Aug-16   Week6
7   29-Aug-16   4-Sep-16    Week7
8   5-Sep-16    11-Sep-16   Week8
9   12-Sep-16   18-Sep-16   Week9
10  19-Sep-16   25-Sep-16   Week10
11  26-Sep-16   2-Oct-16    Week11
12  3-Oct-16    9-Oct-16    Week12
13  10-Oct-16   16-Oct-16   Week13
```

I've tried this:

```
select 
  trunc(date_trunc('week',sysdate)) st_dt,
  trunc(date_trunc('week', sysdate)+6) ed_dt,
  'week'||row_number() over (order by null) as week
```

but it only returns the current week's Monday and Sunday.

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirements? Are you displaying the results of your query, or the output you would like to generate? What is wrong with the SELECT statement that you provided? What have you tried doing and what error did you receive?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.My select statement return only current week date(Monday--Sunday) only .But i need last 90 days date (Monday--Sunday).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` to generate a range of dates:

```
SELECT
  trunc(day)     as start_date,
  trunc(day + 6) as end_date
FROM
  (select date_trunc('week', sysdate) + (generate_series(1, 12) * interval '1 week') as day)
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

This results in:

```
week start  week end
2016-10-24  2016-10-30
2016-10-31  2016-11-06
2016-11-07  2016-11-13
2016-11-14  2016-11-20
2016-11-21  2016-11-27
2016-11-28  2016-12-04
2016-12-05  2016-12-11
2016-12-12  2016-12-18
2016-12-19  2016-12-25
2016-12-26  2017-01-01
2017-01-02  2017-01-08
2017-01-09  2017-01-15
```

Please note that `generate_series()` in Amazon Redshift cannot be joined with existing tables. It can only be used as a "Leader-only" query.